# How to split multiple physical monitors in virtual monitors with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, screen, wayland

I have 3 monitors, each one has 23". I use one in portrait orientation and two in landscape.

I use ubuntu 22.04 and I want to split one of the horizontal monitors in 3 parts and the vertical one in 2 parts.

Is this possible?

Comment: I took some time to look into something this. there is xrandr way which I never got to work. and some other ways but there is no good tool to handle such a thing